# SearchBox Google Maps JS API não retorna resultados da pesquisa

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Boa noite, tenho um mapa obtido através da API JavaScript do Google Maps, e estou fazendo a inserção de um searchBox. Até aí tudo bem, o search box foi inserido e o autocomplete está funcionando.
O problema é que quando é feito o "envio" do campo, ou selecionado algum local pelo autocomplete, nada acontece no mapa (não retorna o resultado pesquisado) como podem conferir aqui http://suconago.com.br/maps/.

O que eu tenho que inserir ao JS para que seja retornado os resultados da busca? Se possível, sem que os pontos que estão marcados desapareçam, apenas levar o foco do mapa para o lugar selecionado, marcando-o.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver.
Substituí o trecho

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });
```

por

```js
       var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     searchBox.set('map', null);


     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
       (function(place) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

           position: place.geometry.location
         });
         marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
           if (!this.getMap()) {
             this.unbindAll();
           }
         });
         bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


       }(place));

     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     searchBox.set('map', map);
     map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));

   });
```